# How do I find out the version number of an installed library?

Tags: rhel, yum, shared-library

Question relevant to RedHat/CentOS.
I'm a little confused between package and library and how to pin them to a fixed version.

There's an X11 rollover bug in recent libxcb versions that affects my C programs. libxcb-1.5-1 doesn't have that bug.

So I did:

```
# yum remove libxcb-devel
# rpm -Uvh --oldpackage libxcb-1.5-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

And now the bug is gone and my software works fine.

Fast forward a few weeks and the bug is back.

```
# yum info libxcb-devel
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Available Packages
Name       : libxcb-devel
Arch       : i686
Version    : 1.9.1
Release    : 2.el6
Size       : 1.0 M
Repo       : sl-security
```

But is that the installed version or the version available through the repo ?
How can I tell which version of libxcb is currently installed ?

```
$ ll /usr/lib/libxcb.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Aug  6 03:38 /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 -> libxcb.so.1.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130752 Oct 14  2014 /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0*
$ readelf -d /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0 | grep SONAME
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libxcb.so.1]
```

So I'm confused between the version number shown by yum, the number on the .so and the number I want...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to know what version is *installed*, just run:

```
rpm -q libxcb-devel
```

If you want to prevent upgrades to this package, you can add the package to the yum `exclude` configuration.  Add the following to the `main` section in `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
exclude=libxcb-devel
```

The library version (e.g., in `libxcb.so.1.1.0`) very seldom tracks the package version, and is meant to track API changes.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # yum remove libxcb-devel
> # rpm -Uvh --oldpackage libxcb-1.5-1.el6.i686.rpm
> ```

These are two different packages. The -devel version is for compiling against, the libxcb package without -devel is what applications will be running against.

Because you removed the -devel version that there isn't anything installed, so "yum info" only shows you the latest available version (you can use the --showduplicates option to see all the versions).
If you want to stop it upgrading, I'd recommend installing/using the versionlock plugin on the libxcb package ... although it an be done manually using excludes.

Also use rpm directly, you can just use: yum downgrade blah.rpm

Comment: yum downgrade didn't seem available. Is that a recent addition ? Thanks for the versionlock tip, I'd never heard of it.

Comment: Removed the devel to avoid risks of static linking, I guess.

Comment: yum downgrade is available since at least RHEL6